# The new Firefox Button doesn't work

Tags: firefox

This button doesn't work anymore. I suppose it has been disabled by the last addon I've tried. I've removed this addon, but the botton in the image below still doesn't work. It appears in the toolbar, but nothing happens when I click over it.

[image]

How can I enable this button again? I would like to avoid a reset/reinstall OF Firefox, if possible.

Comment: Which button do you mean: close or menu?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion: the menu button

Comment: OK. It looks as though you have a solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your query please be informed that the same issue reported is bugzilla and fixed. Please try upgrading the instance and check. To upgrade click **alt** and it will list menu bar from **help** try upgrading the instance to latest version and check

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1065998#c33